# Sequential events modeling in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Our internal OLTP system generates sequential data that represents events triggered by the staff.

Let's assume the sample data below:

| Event | Date | Previsous State | New State | State Name | Staff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CREATE | 2020-10-01 | NULL | 0001 | Desc for 0001 | Joana |
| CHANGE | 2020-10-02 | 0001 | 0002 | Desc for 0002 | Carlos |
| CHANGE | 2020-10-03 | 0002 | 0003 | Desc for 0003 | Joe |
| CHANGE | 2020-10-04 | 0003 | 0002 | Desc for 0002 | Joe |
| CHANGE | 2020-10-05 | 0002 | 0003 | Desc for 0003 | Maria |
| CHANGE | 2020-10-06 | 0003 | 0004 | Desc for 0004 | Maria |

The changes can go back and forth in the chain.

I would like to answer questions like `who did what and when ?`, `what is the common sequencies ?`, `is there any change of state that is not supposed to be ?`

I tried to model the data like this:

```
CREATE 
  (`0001`: Status {id:"0001",name:"Desc for 0001"}) ,
  (`0002`: Status {id:"0002",name:"Desc for 0002"}) ,
  (`0003`: Status {id:"0003",name:"Desc for 0003"}) ,
  (`0004`: Status {id:"0004",name:"Desc for 0004"}) ,
  
  (joana: Person {name:"Joana"}) ,
  (carlos: Person {name:"Carlos"}) ,
  (joe: Person {name:"Joe"}) ,
  (maria: Person {name:"Maria"}) ,
  
  (joana)-[:CREATE {date: "2020-10-01"}]->(`0001`),
  
  (carlos)-[:CHANGE {date: "2020-10-02"} ]->(`0002`),
  (`0001`)-[:NEXT {date: "2020-10-02"}]->(`0002`),

  (joe)-[:CHANGE {date: "2020-10-03"} ]->(`0003`),
  (`0002`)-[:NEXT {date: "2020-10-03"}]->(`0003`),

  (joe)-[:CHANGE {date: "2020-10-04"} ]->(`0002`),
  (`0003`)-[:NEXT {date: "2020-10-04"}]->(`0002`),

  (maria)-[:CHANGE {date: "2020-10-05"} ]->(`0003`),
  (`0002`)-[:NEXT {date: "2020-10-05"}]->(`0003`),

  (maria)-[:CHANGE {date: "2020-10-06"} ]->(`0004`),
  (`0003`)-[:NEXT {date: "2020-10-06"}]->(`0004`)
```

But I'm not sure about this given that is the first time I'm dealing with this.

And I suppose that I should used MERGE instead of CREATE, to reuse the Status nodes (they are shared) and create new relationships for each new change.

What is the best model for this needs ?

Comment: Take a look at https://snowplowanalytics.com/blog/2017/07/17/loading-and-analysing-snowplow-event-data-in-neo4j/

Comment: @TomažBratanič That brings more doubts in my head hehehe. In the blogpost, for each page access a new node is created. Does the page shouldn't be a single node and shared by all the users that access it ? I mean, Shouldn't we create a single page node for "home" and every user that access the Home page should create a new relationship :VIEW for this single shared "home page node" ?

Comment: @TomažBratanič I think that my confusion is about to have or not a single shared node for each possible "Status".

Comment: No, I would create a new node for each event for each user. This way it is much easier to follow user paths, otherwise you would have to have a complicated way of querying to follow a user path

Comment: @TomažBratanič my goal is not to analyze individual user actions, but analyze the process flow itself and give me insights about user relationships with other user. Imagine this like a fraud detection system. If I identify a given user based on a anomaly flow, I would like to dig deeper in ther user's connections with other users. So, having a node for each event, am I able to do that ?

Comment: Well, you start with the user flow, looking for anomalies... So node for each event makes sense... how you connect user to user, I don't know, but it is definitely possible to do additional queries later